# How to Generate XML file from JTree which is dynamically created in java

Tags: java, xml, swing, jtree

Help me to code for generating an xml file from `JTree` which is created dynamically through java code. How to generate the XML file from that? Please explain.

Comment: What kind of XML output do you expect? Could you show with a really small example (a few items) the input and the output? (something like root->Child1-->Child2 and then the XML:`<root><Child1/><Child2/></root>` or `<element name="root"><element name="Child1"/><element name="Child2"/></element>`

Comment: Yes i want to generate xml into format like <root><child1><subchild></subchild></child1><child2><subchild2></subchild2></child2></root>

Answer (score 0):

Since TreeNodes can be serialized you can use xstream to do so.

see http://www.java-forums.org/xml/25994-how-can-i-create-xml-file-jtree-need-ur-valuable-suggestions.html

i.e.:

```
System.out.println(   new XStream().toXml(jtree)    );
```